# C. Two-way merge.Calculate comparisons

Tags: c, sorting, merge, mergesort

Everything seems to be working correctly. But I need to count the comparisons again. For some reason, the program refused to work when I tried to implement it. And in the past times (I mean past sorts), I counted the swaps..well, as far as I understand, there are no swaps in this sorting, so we need to count when we rewrite to another array, right? Please help me calculate this. Preferably immediately with the code.Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void merge( int *a, int lb, int split, int ub) {

  int pos1=lb;
  int pos2=split+1;
  int pos3=0;  
  int *temp = (int*)malloc(ub+1 * sizeof(int));

  while (pos1 <= split && pos2 <= ub) {
    if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2])
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];
    else
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
  }
 
  while (pos2 <= ub)   
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
  while (pos1 <= split)  
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];

 
  for (pos3 = 0; pos3 < ub-lb+1; pos3++)
    a[lb+pos3] = temp[pos3];
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub) { 
  long split;                   

  if (lb < ub) {                
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split);      
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub);
    merge(a, lb, split, ub);    
  }
}
void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    int n = 10;
    int *arr;
    arr = malloc(n * sizeof *arr);                    
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++)
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;
 
    arrprint(arr, n);  
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1);
    arrprint(arr, n);  
 
    free(arr);                                       
    puts("");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535540/exactly-how-many-comparisons-does-merge-sort-make answer your question? does `if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2])` count as comparison?

Comment: Probably counts as a comparison too, at least I think so. As far as I understand, I only need to count comparisons to calculate the time complexity of sorting..But I haven't quite figured out how and where to write it down yet...

Comment: @4386427 I will then do statistics with the table for 100, 200, etc. elements in the array .There will be displayed the number of comparisons for each set.And I will build a schedule. But first, I would like to correctly calculate the comparisons on a fixed array.

Comment: merge sort divides the problem and then *compares* while merging. One way to count the comparisons is to declare an integer variable, set its value initially to 0 and increment its value everytime the code block (between {}) is executed. i.e., in both `if` and `else` part of `if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2]) temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++]; else temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];`

Comment: @rohitt That's exactly what I was trying to do.Only the program did not output any result and ended prematurely.

Comment: @4386427 Perhaps you misunderstood me, I'm sorry if I misled you. I didn't do the implementation with swaps .Moreover, they will not be here at all, I just asked a clarifying question. But how to calculate the comparisons-the question remains open... :)

Comment: @LusindaBabaika Can you explain **why** you want to count the number of comparisons?

Comment: @4386427 I need to create an Excel table and then plot it.As I said above. In previous sorts, I counted the sum of comparisons and swaps.But in this case, only comparisons are needed.But I may still need to count the number of copy operations. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @LusindaBabaika hmm... I think you are trying to compare two things that can't be compared - like "comparing apples and oranges". Anyway ... it seems to me that `temp` serves like a placeholder for a traditional swap so assignment to/from `temp` should probably be counted.

Comment: OT: To me it seems your code is missing some calls of `free`

Answer (score 0):

There are subtle errors in your code. But the following code should work fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void merge( int *a, int lb, int split, int ub, int* count) {

  int pos1=lb;
  int pos2=split+1;
  int pos3=0;
  int *temp = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); // change 5

  while (pos1 <= split && pos2 <= ub) {
    if (a[pos1] <= a[pos2]){
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];
      (*count)++;
    }
    else{
      temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
      (*count)++;
    }
  }

  while (pos2 <= ub)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos2++];
  while (pos1 <= split)
    temp[pos3++] = a[pos1++];


  for (pos3 = 0; pos3 < ub-lb+1; pos3++)
    a[lb+pos3] = temp[pos3];
  
  free(temp); // required
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int lb, int ub, int* count) {
  long split;

  if (lb < ub) {
    split = (lb + ub)/2;

    mergeSort(a, lb, split, count);
    mergeSort(a, split+1, ub, count);
    merge(a, lb, split, ub, count);
  }
}

void arrprint(int *arr, int n) {
    printf("%d", *arr);
    int i;
    for ( i = 1; i < n; i++) printf(" %d", arr[i]);
    puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int n = 10;
    int *arr = NULL; // change 1
    arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr); // change 2
    int c = 0; // change 3, c is in stack
    int* count = &c; // change 4
    srand(time(NULL));
    int s;
    for ( s = 0; s < n; s++ )
        arr[s] = rand() % 50;

    arrprint(arr, n);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, n-1, count);
    arrprint(arr, n);

    free(arr);
    puts("");

    printf("Comparison count: %d\n", *count);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the comparisons are counted by passing an additional int variable through the function calls.

note that it is best practice to check if the memory was actually allocated by `malloc`.

```
arr = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof *arr);
if(arr){
    // ...
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: Oh, great.Thank you very much.Could you please see here what I did wrong?The file is being created, but the values in it are empty, maybe I overlooked something somewhere. https://ideone.com/Ut9emf

Comment: @4386427 No, that's not the problem.I just need to write the results to this file.It's just that I get 0 values everywhere for comparisons.I missed something somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: It is because there is no `free(temp)` in the `merge` function. Adding it, the program will run correctly. I've updated it in my answer.

Comment: @rohitt thanks, but  I still get zero values  https://ideone.com/nm3l05

Comment: @rohitt so...  [Error] 'count' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: I believe there is an extra `int count=0;` in the code that is causing the problem. check if **renaming** that variable to something else solves your problem.